# Creating an EER in MySql Workbench for logging user ip, user agent, date and amount of currency converted

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

For an assignment I have created a currency converter where the user puts in an amount in USD and it converts that into Euros, Canadian Dollars and GBP. I now just need to create a database in which to log the ip address, date visited, amount converted and user agent of anyone who uses the converter. I have all of the front and back end code working and actually connecting and logging in my database now but I can't decide if my schema is correct.

I have only a "logs" table which has `log_ip` and `log_datetime` as the composite PK since a user can convert multiple times. My question really is, should I be handling this differently and having a "users" table which simply has the `user_ip` as a PK and a "logs" table which has the `logs_datetime` as it's PK and of course `user_ip` as a FK?

I'm not sure if there is a good enough reason to split it into two tables as there does not seem to be enough to normalize out. I have not worked with databases very much so I apologize for my noobishness. I tend to over-engineer things and have talked with one of my friends who is a dbadmin and he says to just use one table.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/replies.

Answer (score 0):

For simple logging I like to keep it simple and would have a single table. For something a bit more important than logging, yep - I'd split out IP and UserAgent into two separate tables.

But for logging...nope. Just a single table.